# http/handleRequestForwarding: error forwarding request: error=error during forwarding RPC request errors in Vault logs

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm seeing this line the logs of my Vault instances:

```
http/handleRequestForwarding: error forwarding request: error=error during forwarding RPC request
```

At the same time request forwarding doesn't seem to be working because I'm getting `307` responses when I try to `curl http://vault:8200/v1/secret/foo`. This is a problem since the individual instances aren't accessible from outside my Kubernetes cluster, only way is to use the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use the correct port for `cluster_addr` (or `VAULT_CLUSTER_ADDR` if set via the environment variable) - `8201` instead of `8200`.

Now my Kubernetes config for Vault looks like this:

```
env:
  - name: "POD_IP"
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
  - name: "VAULT_API_ADDR"
    value: "http://$(POD_IP):8200"
  - name: "VAULT_CLUSTER_ADDR"
    value: "http://$(POD_IP):8201"
```